# Parsing CSV to python dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have following DataFrame parsed into Python:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")
```

result:

```
   indexes X_values Y_values
0       IDX1     x1      y1
1       IDX1     x2      y2
2       IDX1     x3      y3
3       IDX1     x4      y4
6       IDX2     x1      y1
9       IDX2     x4      y4
10      IDX3     x1      y1
11      IDX3     x2      y2
```

I need to create dictionaries with each indexes as key and x_values & y_values as list of nested dictionaries.
Output should be like:

```
{"IDX1" : [{"x1": "y1"}, {"x2": "y2"}, {"x3": "y3"}, {"x4": "y4"}],
"IDX2": [{"x1": "y1"},{"x4": "y4"}],
"IDX3":[{"x1": "y1"}, {"x2": "y2"}]}
```

I am trying to parse it using set_index() method but always missing something. Could you help me?

Also, dictionary of nested dictionaries with indexes as keys would be also good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
out = (df.apply(lambda row: {row['X_values']: row['Y_values']}, axis=1)
       .groupby(df['indexes']).agg(list).to_dict())
```

```
print(out)

{'IDX1': [{'x1': 'y1'}, {'x2': 'y2'}, {'x3': 'y3'}, {'x4': 'y4'}], 'IDX2': [{'x1': 'y1'}, {'x4': 'y4'}], 'IDX3': [{'x1': 'y1'}, {'x2': 'y2'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
d = df[['X_values','Y_values']].apply(lambda x : {x[0]:x[1]},axis=1).groupby(df['indexes']).agg(list).to_dict()
Out[104]: 
{'IDX1': [{'x1': 'y1'}, {'x2': 'y2'}, {'x3': 'y3'}, {'x4': 'y4'}],
 'IDX2': [{'x1': 'y1'}, {'x4': 'y4'}],
 'IDX3': [{'x1': 'y1'}, {'x2': 'y2'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to make use of the `to_dict()` method ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)).

You might need to index like you say. I would try:

```py
df.set_index('indexes').T.to_dict('list')
```

Comment: This only returns one pair of x_values & y_values for each indexes.